# How to split my project into modules to be used in multiple platforms?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, websocket, rmi

I have a college project that manages bookmarks, a CRUD with folder structure. The project uses swing and hibernate all in the client. Now I want to make both a web and an android application version, but I don't know how to split the modules. For example, I thought about creating a web application with websockets and hibernate, and connect the swing, web and android in the websocket server.
Is that a good choice? If not, what better options are there?

Please note that the project has to be synchronized between the platforms and
I wonder about the technologies that can be used also, and not just the pattern.

I can use Spring too if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

just an opinion, the project module structure should look like this:

1. android client (androidUI)
2. web client (webUI)
3. service part
4. db
5. integration tests

Comment: Thanks but, what would this service part? I would like more details about the technologies also and not just the pattern, thanks.

Comment: Android and webapp in the client (UI) module, WebSocket layer in the service module and Hibernate in the db module.